Product of uniform distributed random variables converges to 0
$X_1,X_2,...$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that are uniformly distributed in [0,2]. Show that $\prod_{i=1}^N X_i$ converges to 0 in probability. Hint: Use the law of large numbers and Jensen's inequality.
As sums and products are involved I think that Jensen has to be used with the function log. Apart from that I don't know how Jensen could help here.

No Jensen needed. The expectation of the $\log(X_i)$ is: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}[2\log(2)-2]=\log(2)-1$$
Are these integrable? $$\int_0^2|\log(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^2\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=2\log(2)-1<\infty$$
So, yes. By the law of large numbers: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\log(2)-1$$Almost surely. It follows that: $$\sum_{i=1}^n\log(X_i)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\infty$$Almost surely, since $\log(2)-1<0$.
Taking exponentials, we have that: $$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$Almost surely.
The same argument shows that if $t$ is a positive real and $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty\sim\mathcal{U}([0,t])$, then: $$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\begin{cases}0&t<e\\\infty&t>e\end{cases}\quad\text{a.s.}$$I am uncertain about the case $t=e$.

Thank you very much. Correct solutions that don't use official hints ought to be accepted but unfortunately aren't accepted in this course. Can you think of any way to use Jensen for this?

I suspect that if the goal is to show convergence in probabilty that the strong law is over kill?

@Martin Jensen feels quite irrelevant here, frankly. You could use it to apply the weak law to the sum of logs, knowing $\Bbb E[\log(X_i)]\le\log\Bbb E[X_i]=0$, but that’s not strong enough. We need a strict inequality, which Jensen doesn’t give

Here is a proof that does not use the hint, only Markov's inequality.

Let $$q=E\left[\sqrt{X_1}\right] =\frac 12 \int_0^2 \sqrt{t} dt= \frac {2^{3/2}}{3}<1.$$
Therefore $$E\left[\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^n X_j}\right]=q^n \to 0 $$
By Markov's inequality
$$ P\left(\prod_{j=1}^n X_j > \epsilon\right) = P\left(\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^n X_j}>\sqrt{\epsilon}\right) \le q^n \epsilon^{-1/2}\to 0.$$

Note: In 1 we used an explicit computation. However, we can avoid it and use Cauchy Schwarz / Jensen, to generalize it to the following statement: Let $X_1$ be a nonnegative random variable with finite expectation and which is not identically equal to $1$, then $E\left[\sqrt{X_1}\right] < \sqrt{E\left[X_1\right]}$. With this you can repeat 2 and 3 to show that the product of IID nonnegative nondegenerate  RVs with expectation $1$ tends to $0$ in probability.

Unfortunately it's not allowed to ignore the hint.

The fact that $E \sqrt{X_1} < \sqrt{E X_1}$ is an application of Jensen's inequality.

@copper.hat: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something, but -- doesn't this answer already say that?

@ruakh It does, but I am just emphasising for the OP. Albeit it does not use the LLN.

@copper.hat Jensen’s inequality only gives weak inequality, to get the strict inequality we had to explicitly calculate the expectation

@FShrike Strict inequality follows since square root is not affine and the distribution not concentrated at a constant.
